# Solaar (software for BT pairing of Logitech devices) is popping up with error message

Tags: wireless, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth, logitech

Recently I'm having this problem: Solaar is sending **error messages** about my **Logitech Wireless Mouse M525**. Both the mouse and wireless keyboard are working properly.

Any idea **how to fix it?**

[image]

[image]

**Software versions:**

- Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
- Solaar 0.9.2+dfsg-8

**Assuming that I need to do firmware update:**
I entered the following commands:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo service fwupd start
sudo fwupdmgr refresh
sudo fwupdmgr update
```

The last command outputted the following message:
`Not compatible with bootloader version: failed predicate [BOT01.0[0-3]_* regex BOT01.04_B0016]`

Comment: Could you add an example of the error message you get?

Comment: @Hugo: I will post an example as soon I encounter and capture one

Comment: Please post the other question separately, and not in one **post**.

Comment: What version of Solaar? What's the error message? What version Ubuntu?

Comment: @heynnema: I updated the Question with software version information. Error message will be also posted, as soon as I encounter and capture the next one. Unfortunatelly, I didn't take a snapshot when the error message popped up.

Comment: Solaar is currently at version 1.0.1, but I don't think it arrived until the 19.10 repos. Have you updated the firmware in your Logitech Unifying receiver?

Comment: Have you looked at https://pwr-solaar.github.io/Solaar/installation?
The guide there is pretty straight forwards.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact error message that you're receiving, I'm going to have to guess at a possible cure...

Solaar is currently at version 1.0.1, but I don't think it's in the Ubuntu repos until 19.10.

Update the `Logitech Unifying receiver` firmware...

- The `Ubuntu Software` application can update the firmware easily.
- You can also see...

https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/update-your-logitech-wireless-dongle-right-now.htm

https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360032078393-Logitech-Response-to-Research-Findings

Comment: `sudo fwupdmgr update` is outputing:
Not compatible with bootloader version: failed predicate [BOT01.0[0-3]_* regex BOT01.04_B0016]

Comment: @BlueSkies try the methods outlined in my answer. Report back.

Comment: @BlueSkies status please...

Comment: @BlueSkies status please...

Comment: Unfortunately (or on the contrary - fortunately?) - no more messages coming from Solaar...

Comment: @BlueSkies have you successfully updated the dongle firmware?